# Can I observe the change fo a variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I know I can use get a notification when the value of a variable has changed, Code A is OK.

I hope to monitor the change of a normal variable such as `var myFilename="OK"` in Code B, but `myObserv` isn't launching when `myFilename` has changed.

Can I observe the change  fo a variable in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
var savedFilename: String by Delegates.observable("") {
        prop, old, new ->  ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
var myFilename="OK"

var myObserv String by Delegates.observable(myFilename) {
    prop, old, new ->  ...
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do this.

Comment: Imo you'd need a custom setter and what you'd end up with, would be basically what by Delagates.observable does